# How can I create a list with Interface Instances

Tags: c#, list, generics, enums

I have an interface:

```
public Interface IStudent
{
    Students students {get;}
    Boolean CanStayAfterHours;
}

public enum Students
{
    Student1,
    Student2,
    Student3,
    Student4
}
```

How can I add `IStudent` properties to a generic list? `List<IStudent>`?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? Are you simply asking how to create a list of `IStudent` instances?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Yes, Sorry for the confusion. I want to populate the List with IStudent instances

Comment: In that case you want to add `IStudent` **items** to the list, not "properties".  You do it just as you always do: create objects and call `Add`.  The objects you create will have to be of some type or types that implement the `IStudent` interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to have a class that implements that interface:

```
public class Student : IStudent {
    Students students { get; set; } // set, for example
    Boolean CanStayAfterHours { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can add them to a list like this:

```
var studentList = new List<IStudent>() {
    new Student() { CanStayAfterHours = true },
    new Student() { CanStayAfterHours = false, Students = Students.Student1 },
    new Student() { CanStayAfterHours = true },
};
```

Your design doesn't make much sense... but I'll leave that to you to figure out.

Comment: You're code won't compile, you are setting properties such as students which on the interface only has a getter, not a setter

Comment: Eagle eye - thanks for that. Added a setter to show the example.

Comment: Cool, same with setting the Students property

Comment: I should stop debugging while I type answers :P

Answer (score 2):

`IList<IStudent>` can be used to keep a list of IStudent objects. Of course you need a `class Student` that implements `IStudent`, because you cannot create an instance of an interface. The purpose of your enum is unclear, you clearly don't want an enum value for each student, since that would require a rebuild of your application every time a new student signs up.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement a concrete object that implements the interface

public class ConcreteStudent : IStudent {

```
public Students students { get; set; }
public bool CanStayAfterHours { get; set; }
```

}

Some changes where required to the interface, I added some setters to the interface, hope this agrees with your design

public interface IStudent {

```
    Students students { get; set; }
    Boolean CanStayAfterHours { get; set; }
```

}

Then adding these objects to a list, we do the following

```
List<IStudent> students = new List<IStudent>()
students.Add(new ConcreteStudent()
{
 students = Students.Student1,

});
```

Answer (score 0):

interface ListofPatientService
{
List

```
  retriev();

}
class listofServiceDummy : ListofPatientService
{
    List<patientmodel> list = new List<patientmodel>
    {
         new patientmodel(){Name="Abdi", Age= 30, Description=""},
         new patientmodel(){Name="HassaN", Age= 40, Description=""},
          new patientmodel(){Name="Hasna", Age= 35, Description=""},
           new patientmodel(){Name="Moktar", Age= 50, Description=""},
            new patientmodel(){Name="Liban", Age= 55, Description=""},
    };

}
```

Comment: provide more context boosts answer quality and likely up-voting behavior too instead of triggering down-voting ones. Keep in mind you're competing with two other answers already provided to OP. Also look at the markup because there is a  loose "{". End of Review.